# What does V mean by unforeseen circumstances that had accelerated his plans?

Tags: plot-explanation, v-for-vendetta

40 minutes into *V for Vendetta* V tells Evie:

> It appears that unforeseen circumstances have accelerated my original plan.

Now I assume that "unforeseen circumstances" refers to the inspector getting close to the case. But I don't understand how he found out that the inspector had gotten close to the case.

I would like to know if I've missed something or it was just not shown in the movie.

Answer (score 2):

In the original source comic, it would appear that the reason V was so keen to accept Evey's offer of help was simply that it was *convenient to his planning*. Presumably he'd intercepted one of the Bishop's semi-regular communications with the pimp who supplied his underage girls and knew that this presented an opportunity to attack him at a moment of weakness; both in terms of his personal security and in terms of his moral frailty.

[image]

Notably, in the [original version](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/V-for-Vendetta.html) of the script, the line remains much unchanged

> **EVEY:** *I want to help you, V.  I want to do something.  Can we make a
> deal?*
>
> **V:** *Yes.  I think we can make a deal if you like.  **I think I know a way
> you could help me very soon indeed.***

---

If I had to guess, the "unforeseen circumstances" line reflects a slight change between the comics and the film. At this point in the film Finch has already discovered the connection between V and Larkhill (by looking at Prothero's record), something that doesn't occur in the books until far later (when he discovers the Doctor's diary).